# Django: no reverse url match with multiple parameters

Tags: django, django-urls

My URLs need to capture the following:

```
domain/forum-name/
domain/forum-name/topic-name
```

I have the following URL definitions:

```
url(r'^$', views.index_forums, name='index_forums'),
url(r'^(?P<forum_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<topic_name>[-\w]+)/$', views.show_topic, name='show_topic'),
url(r'^(?P<forum_name>[-\w]+)/$', views.index_topics, name='index_topics'),
```

When I hit a URL like domain/name-of-forum, I generate URLs in the HTML like so:

```
{% url 'board:show_topic' forum_name|lower topic.title|lower %}
```

This gives me a "Reverse...not found" error, and I cannot figure out why. Am I using "url" incorrectly? Is there a problem with my regular expression? Thanks!

Edit: adding full error and template:

```
NoReverseMatch at /random/
Reverse for 'show_topic' with arguments '(u'random', u'funny youtube videos')' and keyword    arguments '{}' not found.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/random/
Django Version: 1.5c2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'show_topic' with arguments '(u'random', u'funny youtube videos')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Exception Location: /Users/travis/code/penv/lib/python2.7/site- packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 424
Python Executable:  /Users/travis/code/penv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2

Reverse for 'show_topic' with arguments '(u'random', u'funny youtube videos')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
1   {% extends "board/base.html" %}
2   
3   {% block content %}
4   {% if topic_list %}
5   <ul>
6   {% for topic in topic_list %}
7       <li><a href="{% url 'board:show_topic' forum_name|lower topic.title|lower %}">{{topic.title}}</a></li>
8   {% endfor %}
9   </ul>
10  {% else %}
11  <p>No topics! <a href="/topic/new/">Make a new one</a>.</p>
12  {% endif %}
13  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error text?

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: Added to original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
{% url 'show_topic' forum_name|lower topic_name|lower %}
```

---

Edit:

Your url regex doesn't accept spaces:

Try:

```
url(r'^(?P<forum_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<topic_name>[-\w\ ]+)/$', views.show_topic, name='show_topic'),
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I have the app namespaced like so:url(r'^', include('board.urls', namespace="board")),

Comment: Which version of django are you using? Some versions don't accept quotes in named urls.

Comment: Did you try using positional args? For ex `forum_name=forum_name topic_name=topic.title`

Comment: It doesnt look like your regex accepts spaces. Either `slugify` to add `-` characters or try above regex.

Comment: Damn, that was it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah, I need to slugify. That was a stupid bug. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing. Sometimes just needs an extra pair of eyes.