# Namespacing URL names with multiple parameters in Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I properly reference the edit_product.html line to the Edit_Product in urls.py with 2 parameters?

I tried looking for examples but I couldn't find any.

This is the error I received:

Reverse for 'Edit_Product' with arguments '('eiffel',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shop/edit_product/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='shop'

urlpatterns = [

    path('create_product/', views.CreateProduct, name='Create_Product'),
    path('edit_product/<slug:c_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/', views.EditProduct, name='Edit_Product'),
    path('', views.allProdCat, name='allProdCat'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>/', views.allProdCat, name='products_by_category'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/', views.ProdCatDetail, name='ProdCatDetail'),
]
```

edit_product.html

```
<td><a href="{% url 'shop:Edit_Product' category.slug | product.slug %}">{{ product.name }}</a></td>
```

Comment: Don't you need two parameters here? Why do you write `|` in your `{% url ... %}`.

Comment: i tried to imitate this solution that was in django1.5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181278/django-no-reverse-url-match-with-multiple-parameters

Comment: path('edit_product/<slug:c_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/', views.EditProduct, name='Edit_Product')

and

 path('<slug:c_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/edit_product', views.EditProduct, name='Edit_Product'),

would it still work the same if I type the following in the html:
<a  href="{% url 'shop:Edit_Product' category.slug  product.slug %}">

Answer (score 1):

You don't need | just separate those with space

`<a  href="{% url 'shop:Edit_Product' category.slug  product.slug %}">`